# Azure traffic manager Weighted routing , how much wight matters?

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

In azure traffic manager for endpoints we assign weights, i have two endpoint where one endpoint(endpoint1) have weight as 1 and other(endpoint2) as weight 2 , i understand more  traffic will go to endpoint2 but by how much ? is it like 2 out of 3 requests will go to endpoint2 and 1 out of 3 will go to endpoint1.

if i change it as

endpoint1 - 1
endpoint2 - 100

what will be the impact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they use ratio. So if you have following weights: 1 and 2, it will route third of the traffic to the first endpoint and two thirds to the second.

With your values (1 and 100) it will route something like 0.9% to the first endpoint and  99.1% to the second endpoint.

Comment: even i assume so, but is it documented or have you tested it anytime?

Comment: I didnt test it to confirm the exact numbers, but I've used weighted routing and it works like that, also its quite obvious from the explanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#weighted-traffic-routing-method

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with the first poster, you can check it on windows with running it from the command line like:

```
for ($i=0;$i -lt 50;$i++) { ipconfig /flushdns |grep aldkjf ; nslookup lbtest-abcd.trafficmanager.net | grep lbtest }
```

you may need to install grep, or use whatever window equivalent is.

This would give a bunch of entries like:

```
lbtest####.azurewebsites.net
lbtesteast#####.azurewebsites.net
```

for me counting the east lines, it gave totals of entries hitting east
7,18,11,7,10 (or 53/250) with my weighting of 15 on west and 5 on east which works out to 21.2% hitting east and 78.8 hitting west.

Answer (score 0):

There no specific percentage for weighted. When configuring weighted the higher value has more priority. So if we put endpoint 1= 50 & endpoint 2= 70 more traffic will route to endpoint 2

Reference - [Azure Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#weighted)